# Using namespaces inside template implementation files

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, include, header-files

To keep class definition in header file clean, I decided to move implementations of templated functions into another `*.h` file, which I include in the main header. Now I would like to make use of `using namespace` there, to make code more readable.

But using namespaces would affect the whole application, since the file gets included in the header which itself gets included in the whole application. The `using` of the namespaces would spread out of the file.

How can I handle this?

Comment: `using namespace XX` only extends to the scope that encloses `using namespace`.  So if you keep `using namespace` inside method definitions, for example, it won't "spill out."  Unfortunately, you can't use these at the `class` level.  (ie. `class foo { using namespace std; ... }`)

Comment: is the class defined in a namespace?

Comment: @JoeZ Could I just wrap everything in the templates file with `{` `}` to create an encapsulate scope?

Comment: @elyashiv No, its not.

Comment: I do not get it: namespace Whatever { { template class Declaration{}; } } and namespace Whatever { template Declaration::definition() {} } is just fine - no need for using namespace.

Comment: @DieterLücking Inside the implementation of a templated function, I often use the `std::tr2::sys` namespace.

Comment: @danijar Hence you answered your question yourself!

Comment: @DieterLücking Okay, so I should `using` the namespace inside the method implementation? Or is there a per file way?

Comment: @danijar As long you are not getting into a global (or library namespace) all is good - hence using whatever in a function is fine.

Comment: @JoeZ Putting using directives inside functions is what I ended up doing. If you would write a short answer, I'd mark it as accepted.

Comment: @JoeZ Sadly, `namespace my_ns { using namespace std; .... } using namespace my_ns;` in a header has exactly the same undesirable effect as a direct `using namespace std;` in the header... (And nit-pick: `using namespace std;` is called a “using _directive_”; `using std::cout;` is an actual “using declaration”.)

Comment: @JoeZ Sadly that's incorrect. It _will_ inject `namespace std` into the outer scope. [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f5685c0acac43dc). So, that's sad, but the “rule” is simple: never write “`using namespace`” at top level in a header.

Comment: @gx_: Urgl... deleted my comments suggesting `namespace my_ns`.  I somehow had munged up my local test.  You are correct.  My error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put `using namespace XX` inside function definitions to scope the using declaration to that function:

```
int func( ...args... )
{
    using namespace std; 
    // ... body of function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a namespace alias.

```
namespace submod_ = topspace::other_project::module::submodule;
```

Then you can use `submod_` wherever you would require the very long namespace.

This requires you to still use `submod_` where you would have the long namespace qualifier.  In that sense, it doesn't exactly answer your question.  But I would argue that the explicitness of the qualification aids readability and helps prevent mistakes.

There are real examples of StackOverflow questions where a "using" declaration brought in "lurking" functions which the code author did not realize.

Comment: My main concern is that namespace using would spread over to other files that include my header. That would be the same with aliases, I guess.

Comment: I understand.  I think the namespace alias spreading over is less dangerous.  With a `using` directive, functions and types are silently added to the lookup set in client code (i.e. the code that includes your header).  With a namespace alias, the client code would need to actively prefix a type or function with the `submod_::` alias (in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You can place the `using namespace` in the `namespace` of your 'main header':

Header.h

```
#include <string>

namespace Test
{
    using namespace std;

    string f()
    {
        return "Test";
    };
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    Test::f();  

    string test;        // Error: identifier "string" is undefined
    std::string test;   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, but I am talking about template implementations, they must be included at the end of the header as far as I know.

Comment: @danijar This example applies to all sorts of implementations. So you can also place the `using namespace` inside the `namespace` of your templated functions header.

Comment: Hmm, that currently has doesn't live in a namespace. I'll think of changing that.